# Alternate Characterization of Rate of Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, large-deviation-theory, rate-of-convergence

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence converging to $L$.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence), if there exists a $\mu\in(0,1)$ satisfying

$$\lim_{k→∞}\frac{|x_{k+1}−L|}{|x_k−L|}=μ$$

then we say $\{x_n\}$ converges *linearly* to $L$ and has a *rate of convergence* of $\mu$.  If $\mu = 0$ we say $\{x_n\}$ converges *superlinearly* and if $\mu = 1$ we say $\{x_n\}$ converges *sublinearly*.

**My question is:**

If $\{x_n\}$ converges to $L$, does the following hold? (**See update below**)

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|x_k|^{1/k} = \lim_{k→∞}\frac{|x_{k+1}−L|}{|x_k−L|}.$$

Intuitively these two limits seem like they should convey similar information about the speed of convergence, and trying a few simple sequences gave equivalent results.

**Context:**

This came up while studying [Cramér's theorem of Large Deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem#Large_deviations).
Without getting into the specifics here, the theorem can be stated as the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{Pr}(M_n \geq x)^{1/n} = e^{-I(x)}$$

and the sources I am reading discuss (informally) that this result implies that the probability in the left hand side decays exponentially with $n$, but I do not understand why that is implied.  My guess is that it is related to my question.

****Update:**  I was mistaken in my original question.  As Fred pointed out, the equality was trivially false.

I am actually interested in whether the following holds:

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|x_k - L|^{1/k} = \lim_{k→∞}\frac{|x_{k+1}−L|}{|x_k−L|}.$$

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_k \to L \ne 0$, then $|x_k| \to |L|>0$. Then there is $K$ such that

$\frac{1}{2}|L| \le x_k \le \frac{3}{2}|L|$ for all $k>K$.

Hence: $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|x_k|^{1/k}=1$.

Comment: Good call. I will admit I only considered the case in which $L = 0$.  Do you think there is anything that can be said with that further restriction?